# Green layer appear each time exporting video using AVExportSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am exporting a video with Some modifications. 
After I get that exported video, I have the option to apply some more modifications Like Watermarking, Cropping, Video Rotation when I apply this transformation and export again the video quality is disturbed a strange green layer started appearing. Every time I export that video the green layer gets darker and darker. I am using the below code for exporting.

```
AVAssetExportSession *export = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
export.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];
if(videoComposition){
    export.videoComposition = videoComposition;
}
if(audioComposition){
    export.audioMix = audioComposition;
}


export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
export.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (export.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {

            completionHandler([export.outputURL relativePath],nil);

        } else {

            completionHandler(nil,export.error.localizedDescription);

        }
    });
}];
```

Comment: is there any way to export video without using AVExportSession as I have studied in some links that it applies H.624 Codec compression and H.624 compression is disturbing alpha channel.

Comment: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post4_h_264_video_with_an_alpha_channel/index.html

Comment: Is there anyway to export video without this codec.